# Error importando modulos en Python

Tags: python, angular

Estoy desarrollando un app con Angular para el Front y Python (webapp2) como backend todo sobre App Engine.

En este punto necesito usar Oauth2 de Google para solicitar un token de autorización.

Según la documentación de Google. Tengo que importar los modulos correspondientes

```
import google.oauth2.credentials
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
```

Antes los instalo con pip

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
pip install --upgrade google-auth google-auth-oauthlib google-auth-httplib2
```

Esta montado en un entorno virtual.
Después de ejecutar dev_appserver.py app.yaml todo va bien, pero si actualizo la web me devuelve:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/home/nacho/altostratusCS/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import google.oauth2.credentials
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/runtime/sandbox.py", line 1149, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named google.oauth2
```

A que puede deberse que no reconozca el modulo si ya está instalado con pip?

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución en la documentación de Google Cloud.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27?authuser=1

1. Lo primero es crear un directorio "lib" dentro del proyecto.
2. Instalar las librerías necesarias con `pip install -t lib/ <library_name>`
3. Cree un archivo nombrado appengine_config.pyen la misma carpeta que su app.yaml archivo.
4. El archivo recien creado debe contener

```html
# appengine_config.py
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

# Add any libraries install in the "lib" folder.
vendor.add('lib')
```

Finalmente me funcionó después de seguir estos pasos.

Answer (score 0):

¿Has activado el entorno virtual antes de instalar los módulos?

El error puede deberse a que estas instalando los módulos fuera del entorno virtual. Prueba a activar el entorno virtual y después ejecuta el comando pip.

Comment: Si, lo he activado pero el problema persiste

Comment: ¿Quizás el problema sea la versión de python que estas utilizando? Para instalar nuevos módulos en python 3 el comando seria pip3.